# Исключение повторяющихся значений поля PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Имеется следующий запрос

```
with H as (Select distinct (REGEXP_MATCHES("Msg", ('\.*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')))[1] as ip, "Dt"::date as visitdate
       from public."Log")
Select ROW_number() over() as id, count(distinct h.ip), h.visitdate
from H
WHERE h.visitdate >= dateFrom AND h.visitdate < dateTo+1 GROUP BY h.visitdate ORDER BY h.visitdate desc;
```

В результирующем наборе H есть повторяющиеся IP. Как можно удалить из H записи, где IP повторяются вне зависимости от даты?

Answer (score 0):

Решением стало использование агрегирующей функции min() на поле "Dt" в CTE.
Т.е мы возвращаем минимальную дату, которой соответствует IP.

В итоге запрос стал таким

```
with H as (Select (REGEXP_MATCHES("Msg", ('\.*\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')))[1] as ip, min("Dt")::date as visitdate
   from public."Log")
Select ROW_number() over() as id, count(distinct h.ip), h.visitdate
from H
WHERE h.visitdate >= dateFrom AND h.visitdate < dateTo+1 GROUP BY h.visitdate ORDER BY h.visitdate desc;
```

На выходе получаем поля id, ip и visitdate, в которую этот ip встретился впервые.